# Не отображается статика в админке

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Запилил небольшой сайт, который в будущем планирую расширять.

На боевом сервере не отображаются стили в админке. Причем на страницах сайта все стили подгружаются и работают.

settings.py:

```py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from landings import views as landings

urlpatterns = [
    path('', landings.index, name='landing'),
    path('cv/', landings.cv, name='cv'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
              + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

конфиг сервера:
[image: конфиг сервера nginx]

вот, что показывает Chrome dev tools при попытке зайти в админку:
[image: output chrome dev tools]
[image: output chrome dev tools]

Команда `./manage.py collectstatic` выполнена. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Вот часть дерева папок на сервере:

```bsh
│       └── __pycache__
├── media
│   └── docs
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── montserrat
│   ├── img
│   │   └── bg
│   └── js
├── staticfiles
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── vendor
│   │   │       └── select2
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── img
│   │   │   └── gis
│   │   └── js
│   │       ├── admin
│   │       └── vendor
│   │           ├── jquery
│   │           ├── select2
│   │           │   └── i18n
│   │           └── xregexp
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── montserrat
│   ├── img
│   │   └── bg
│   └── js
└── templates
    └── landings
```

При включенном DEBUG проблема не исчезает. Сайт висит работает, можете посмотреть [здесь](https://hello.salamatov.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой конфиг статики для nginx:

```
location /static  {
    alias /home/ubuntu/hello/staticfiles;
}
```

P.S. Добавьте условие `if debug` в `urls.py`, чтобы django раздавал медиа и статику только в `debug` моде

Comment: Добавил код по вашему совету, но теперь статика не отображается в принципе)

Comment: @SergeyS. а до этого статика работала?

Comment: да, на сайте отображалась, а в админке – нет

Comment: @SergeyS. статика в какой папке лежит?

Comment: Создается в папке `static`, а после `manage.py collectstatic` копируется в `staticfiles`

Comment: @SergeyS. обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало. Подскажите, а чем отличается `root` от `alias`? По другому, что поменялось

Comment: @SergeyS. если указать `root`, то файл будет искаться по пути `/home/ubuntu/hello/staticfiles/static`, если указать `alias`, то путь будет `/home/ubuntu/hello/staticfiles`. При `alias` путь указанный в `location` будет заменяться на тот, что указан в директиве `alias`, а при `root` они складываются. Сложно, но я хз как по-другому объяснить, можете посмотреть в документации)